# Greater Than or Equal not Working properly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run the following code:

```
UPDATE sb_actprod_reins.psold_ho_mapping_trended SET EG = 14  WHERE   iexpos2 <=75 AND iexpos2 > 70;
UPDATE sb_actprod_reins.psold_ho_mapping_trended SET EG = 15  WHERE   iexpos2 <=80 AND iexpos > 75 ;
```

It is supposed to bucket the data based on iexpos2. It works fine between the end points. However, when it is on the endpoints e.g. 75.1 it does not fall into a bucket. Here is a sample of the output:
[image]

As you can see the data is not getting bucketed on the endpoints. I also tried changing eg to `NUMERIC` from `INTEGER` but that did not work.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You are using iexpos instead of iexpos2. Also, perhaps it is better if you use `iexpos2 BETWEEN 75 AND 80`

Comment: @Dan looking at the OPs code he doesn't want to use the BETWEEN operator as he is using a half open half closed range and BETWEEN only does fully closed ranges.

Comment: Dan was correct. Dumb newbie mistake on my part. The BETWEEN clause was unnecessary.

Comment: @JoeJam Don't be too hard on yourself; that happens to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `UPDATE` condition to use consistently field names:

```
... WHERE   iexpos2 <=80 AND iexpos > 75 ;
```

should be

```
...WHERE   iexpos2 <=80 AND iexpos2 > 75 ;
```